# Process monitor script bash, how to add below wait time, interval and logs capability

Tags: linux, centos, bash, scripting

I am using below script to monitor some processes on linux and restart if process is down and send email.

I want to add below improvements in this script, I need help in that case. Can anyone help with examples

- Seconds to wait between attempts to restart service
- Number of attempts before giving up
- Check interval in seconds
- Generate logs in case of events.

Current script:

```
###edit the following
export smtp=smtprelay.domainname.com:25
service=splunk
email=mailID@xyz.com
###You can provide multiple mail ID's above in email variable separated by commas
###stop editing

host=`hostname -f`
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 2 ))
then
echo "$service is running"
else
/opt/splunk/bin/$service restart
if (( $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $service | wc -l) > 2 ))
then
subject="$service at $host has been started"
echo "$service at $host wasn't running and has been started" | mailx -s "$subject" $email
else
subject="$service at $host is not running"
echo "$service at $host is stopped and cannot be started!!!" | mailx -s "$subject" $email
fi
fi
```

Comment: If you use the fresh centos use the out-of-box systemd functionality. If you use the old centos, use the monit or something like.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need several variables for the attempts counter and the timeouts.
2. Write these values into the some file in `/etc/sysconfig/` directory (`/etc/default/` in other distros) and include it into your script.
3. Use `sleep` to wait a timeout.
4. Use `logger` utility to write data into syslog.
5. Most complex part is the start of service and abort the start if timeout expires. Better use `daemon()` function (`start-stop-daemon` utility in other distros).

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton, I managed to create the script.

[link] (https://github.com/azizzoaib786/bash-scripts)